# Access Value From ObservableCollection from ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I've created the following SQLite table.

```
public class Settings
{

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The SQLite table gets filled in the following code.

```
public partial class SQL : ContentPage
{
    private SQLiteAsyncConnection _connection;
    private ObservableCollection<Settings> _settings;

    public SQL()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        _connection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDb>().GetConnection();
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        await _connection.CreateTableAsync<Settings>();

        var settings_name = new Settings { Name = "Meaning of Life", Value = "42" };
        await _connection.InsertAsync(settings_name);

        await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Value Added to database!", "OK");


        var settings = await _connection.Table<Settings>().ToListAsync();
        _settings = new ObservableCollection<Settings>(settings);
        ListView.ItemsSource = _settings;

        base.OnAppearing();
    }

    void MyItemTapped (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayAlert("Alert", e.ToString(), "OK");
    }
}
```

This is then put into a ListView with the following XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="BudgetBuddy.SQL">
    <ContentPage.Content>
                <ListView x:Name="ListView" ItemTapped="MyItemTapped" ItemSelected="MyItemSelected">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

My question is how would I be able to show the value 42, when someone presses the item "Meaning of Life" in the ListView?

I tried different things for e.ToString(), such as e.Item but does not exist in the System.EventArgs. I think that I need to check something different than the System.EventArgs. I think System.EventArgs is called a namespace, is this correct? and how would I know what other valid options I can choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do it on "ItemSelected" event

```
    private void MyItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selected = e.SelectedItem as Settings;
        DisplayAlert("Alert", selected.Value, "OK");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Anastasia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50330396/4825351) is almost right. I used the `ItemTappedEvent` instead and made small adjustments to access the object:

```
private void MyItemSelected(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    var settings = e.Item as Settings;
    DisplayAlert("Alert",  settings.Value, "OK");
}
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is that when you press on an item in the ListView it will display a DisplayAlert with the associated value from the pressed ListView. Which can be found in the ObservableCollection.

Comment: Can I get an explanation for the downvote please so I can improve my answer? The code should be working.

Comment: I did not downvote you, I don't even have enough rep to downvote people.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why, but your solutions throws the following error "System.NullReferenceException has been thrown" at "var settings = textcell.BindingContext as Settings;"

Comment: Sorry for some reason I assumed you're using a `TapGestureRecognizer`. See my edited answer and try again please.

Comment: I'm still getting a "System.NullReferenceException has been thrown" error, but now it's located at "DisplayAlert("Alert", settings.Value, "OK");"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171077/discussion-between-dennis-schroer-and-john-cadac).